# What is the best way to handle metadata with TileStache?

Tags: leaflet, metadata, tilestache

When I'm serving up maps and UtfGrids with tileStache I would like to also include some metadata with the layers so that my leaflet application can understand the context of the layer. For example: category, data, title, etc.

What is the best way to handle metadata with TileStache?